# Reportlab dynamic information in pagetemplate

Tags: python, reportlab, platypus

I have to convert a long formatted text document to a PDF using `ReportLab`. My objective is to read text file page by page (1 page in text file is of variable length and is determined by form feed). Then for each page I have to write static portion of page using `onPage` function of page template along with inserting dynamic portion into one or more pages of pdf file.

Issue is my `onPage` function is not called until I call `build` for the document. What is the alternative solution to create pdf pages dynamically, while reading text pages.

Here is the part of the script trying to write static content of the page.

```
#Globals
formlines = []
header = []
footer = []
detail_lines = []
def processForm():
    # First 15 lines header
    # Then variable number of detail lines
    # Last 15 line footer
  header = formlines[0:14]
  print "Processing form\n"
  footer = formlines[-15:-1]
  detail_lines = formlines[15:-15]

def firstPgCanv(c, doc):
  # Process header
  pract_addr = header[0][0:43] + "\n" + header[1] + "\n" + header[2][0:43]  
  remit_to = header[8][44:] + "\n" + header[9][44:] + "\n" + header[10][44:]
  guar_addr = header[8][1:42] + "\n" + header[9][1:42] + "\n" + header[10][1:42]

  c.saveState()
  c.translate(.3 * inch, 0 * inch)

  tx = c.beginText(.3 * inch,height- .35 * inch)
  tx.textLines(header_addr)
  c.drawText(tx)

  curY = curY - gap 
# Create text object
  tx = c.beginText(.3 * inch, curY * inch)
  tx.textLines(guar_addr)
  c.drawText(tx)

  tx = c.beginText(4.3 * inch, curY * inch)
  tx.textLines(remit_to)
  c.drawText(tx)

  c.restoreState()

def main(argv=None):
  if argv is None:
    argv = sys.argv

  args = sys.argv[1:]

  #Open source file
  src_file  = sys.argv[1]
  dest = sys.argv[2]
  dest_file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(src_file), dest);

  f=open(src_file, 'r')
  #Document Template
  doc = BaseDocTemplate(dest_file,
                        pagesize=letter,
                        leftMargin=.3*inch,
                        rightMargin= .1 * inch,
                        topMargin= .1 * inch,
                        bottomMargin=.3 * inch,
                        showBoundary=1)

  # Frames
  frameT = Frame(doc.leftMargin + 2*inch, doc.bottomMargin, doc.width - 2.01*inch, doc.height - 4.1*inch, id='normal', showBoundary=0)
  frameB = Frame(doc.leftMargin+2, doc.bottomMargin, 7.5*inch, 10*inch, id='small', showBoundary=1)

  # Page Templates
  doc.addPageTemplates([PageTemplate(id='First',frames=frameT,onPage=firstPgCanv),
                        PageTemplate(id='Later',frames=frameB,onPage=othPgCanv)
                      ])

  Elements = []
  # Process the input file
  while 1:
    ln = f.readline()
    if len(ln) == 0:    # EOF
      break

    s = chomp(ln)

    ff = s.find("\f")    
    if ff != -1:        # \f found along with first line of next form
      frag = s.split("\f")
      final = frag.pop()
      formlines.append(final)
      processForm()
      Elements.append(NextPageTemplate('First'))
      Elements.append(PageBreak)
      # Here I will write few more pages of page Template 'Later'
    else:
      formlines.append(s)

# EOF -- close and flush last page 
  f.close()  
  doc.build(Elements)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

Answer (score 0):

After some research I concluded that there was no way to handle it dynamically. The only workaround left was to access whole file into a list. And then `onPage` function of page template uses a global variable to keep track of page# and accesses appropriate lines of list based on page#.